# sco-unix - unixware + netcat utility

Tags: sco-unix

I need help about the NC (NETCAT utility)

in the official site: http://netcat.sourceforge.net/

I dont have information if netcat utility also fit for unixware

is it possible to install the netcat on unixware?

yael

Answer (score 0):

See Tony Lawrence's article on [Where do I get "netcat" and how do I use it?](http://aplawrence.com/SCOFAQ/FAQ_scotec7getnetcat.html) which covers Unixware.

I believe any non-ancient version of Unixware will run most OpenServer 5 binaries.

Note: there are several different versions of netcat. They all have similar core functionality.

Comment: so you think that netcat will be installe on SCO unix without problems ?

Comment: Probably. For netcat, installation is simply placing the single binary executable file into a suitable directory and giving it suitable permissions. The netcat at http://www.aljex.com/bkw/sco/#rlpnc is bunded in a compressed tar archive - so you don't install using OpenServer's native package manager / software installation tool `custom`. I would uncompress, untar and move the `netcat` file to `/usr/local/bin` then `chmod ugo+rx /usr/local/bin/netcat`

Comment: THX I will install the netcat and I will see -:)